# How to get values of enums stored in an array in PHP 8.1

Tags: php, enums, php-8.1

I would like to apply `array_values( $array_of_enums )` on array of enums ...

```
enum MonEnum: string{
  case Case1 = 'one';
  case Case2 = 'two';
  case Case3= 'three';
}

$array_of_enums = [ MonEnum::Case1, MonEnum::Case2 ]; 

array_values($array_of_enums); // I would like as output [ 'one', 'two' ]
```

but I got this error :

> Object of class XXXX could not be converted to string in ...

So I wander how to get easily enum values store in an array and NOT all values existing for an enum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, `array_values` returns what it is designed to return: a list of values of the array. But each case of the enum class is an instance of that class, so the result would be an array of objects.

If you need an array of primitive string values you have to make it by yourself.
There is the `->value` attribute to get the underlying primitive value. `array_map` is one of the options here. This piece of code should work as you requested

```php
    enum MonEnum: string{
      case Case1 = 'one';
      case Case2 = 'two';
      case Case3= 'three';
    }

    $array_of_enums = [ MonEnum::Case1, MonEnum::Case2 ]; 

    $result = array_map(fn(MonEnum $e) => $e->value, $array_of_enums));

    // now $result contains 2 strings "one" and "two"
    print_r($result); // will output Array ( [0] => one [1] => two )
```

You can try this example at https://onlinephp.io/c/35657c

Answer (score -1):

For the moment I create this function :

```
/**
 * @param UnitEnum[] $array_of_enums
 * @return array|false
 * @throws JsonException
 */
function array_enum_values( array $array_of_enums ){
  $output = [];
  foreach ( $array_of_enums as $enum ){
    if( !$enum instanceof \UnitEnum ){
      error_log( sprintf( "array_enum_values() cannot be executed correctly, one value is not an enum : %s", json_encode( $enum, JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR ) ) );
      return false;
    }else{
      $output[] = $enum->value;
    }
  }
  return $output;
}
```